# How can i sort/filter an NSArray for the following needs?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, filtering

can somebody please show me a way to filter/sort my array in a correct way?

My current Playground i have is the following:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

var candidates: NSArray = ["Berlin-Lichtenberg", "Berlin-Lichterfelde Ost", "Berlin-Lichterfelde West", "Braunsdorf-Lichtenwalde", "Darmstadt-Lichtwiese", "Lichtenberg (Erzgeb)", "Lichtenfels", "Lichtenrade", "Lichtenstein (Sachs)", "Lichtentanne (Sachs)", "Lichtentanne (Thür)", "Lichtenthal", "Lichterfelde Süd", "Rostock Lichtenhagen", "Hamburg", "München", "Köln", "Bonn"]

var root = "Licht"

var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(SELF BEGINSWITH[c] %@) OR (SELF MATCHES[c] %@)", root, NSString(format: ".*[^\\w]%@.*", root))

var filteredArray = NSMutableArray(array: candidates.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate))

println(filteredArray)
```

This would print out the following:

```
(
"Berlin-Lichtenberg",
"Berlin-Lichterfelde Ost",
"Berlin-Lichterfelde West",
"Braunsdorf-Lichtenwalde",
"Darmstadt-Lichtwiese",
"Lichtenberg (Erzgeb)",
Lichtenfels,
Lichtenrade,
"Lichtenstein (Sachs)",
"Lichtentanne (Sachs)",
"Lichtentanne (Thu\U0308r)",
Lichtenthal,
"Lichterfelde Su\U0308d",
"Rostock Lichtenhagen"
}
```

This is all just working fine but the sorting of the Array i would need is a different one and i don't get it right :(

here's how it should look like:

```
(
"Lichtenberg (Erzgeb)",
Lichtenfels,
Lichtenrade,
"Lichtenstein (Sachs)",
"Lichtentanne (Sachs)",
"Lichtentanne (Thu\U0308r)",
Lichtenthal,
"Lichterfelde Su\U0308d",
"Berlin-Lichtenberg",
"Berlin-Lichterfelde Ost",
"Berlin-Lichterfelde West",
"Braunsdorf-Lichtenwalde",
"Darmstadt-Lichtwiese",
"Rostock Lichtenhagen"
)
```

So i would need the results starting with the words my searched string (root) which is "Licht" begins with and THEN it should show the other ones where it is only contained in.

how may i be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let candidates: [String] = ["Berlin-Lichtenberg", "Berlin-Lichterfelde Ost", "Berlin-Lichterfelde West", "Braunsdorf-Lichtenwalde", "Darmstadt-Lichtwiese", "Lichtenberg (Erzgeb)", "Lichtenfels", "Lichtenrade", "Lichtenstein (Sachs)", "Lichtentanne (Sachs)", "Lichtentanne (Thür)", "Lichtenthal", "Lichterfelde Süd", "Rostock Lichtenhagen", "Hamburg", "München", "Köln", "Bonn"].sorted{$0 < $1}

let root = "Licht"

var filtered: [String] = []

filtered += candidates.filter{$0.hasPrefix(root)}
filtered += candidates.filter{$0.hasPrefix(root) == false && $0.rangeOfString(root, options: nil) != nil}

println(filtered) // "[Lichtenberg (Erzgeb), Lichtenfels, Lichtenrade, Lichtenstein (Sachs), Lichtentanne (Sachs), Lichtentanne (Thür), Lichtenthal, Lichterfelde Süd, Berlin-Lichtenberg, Berlin-Lichterfelde Ost, Berlin-Lichterfelde West, Braunsdorf-Lichtenwalde, Darmstadt-Lichtwiese, Rostock Lichtenhagen]"
```

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using the Swift Array type rather than `NSArray`, and using  `filter` combined with the `sort` method, which takes a closure determining the sort order of 2 elements.

In your case, it would be implemented as:

```
var candidates = ["Berlin-Lichtenberg", "Berlin-Lichterfelde Ost", "Berlin-Lichterfelde West", "Braunsdorf-Lichtenwalde", "Darmstadt-Lichtwiese", "Lichtenberg (Erzgeb)", "Lichtenfels", "Lichtenrade", "Lichtenstein (Sachs)", "Lichtentanne (Sachs)", "Lichtentanne (Thür)", "Lichtenthal", "Lichterfelde Süd", "Rostock Lichtenhagen", "Hamburg", "München", "Köln", "Bonn"]

let root = "Licht"

var results = candidates.filter {
    $0.rangeOfString(root) != nil
}.sorted { (lhs: String, rhs: String) -> Bool in
    if startsWith(lhs, root) {
        if (startsWith(rhs, root)) {
            // Both start with root, so return the string comparison
            return lhs < rhs
        }
        // lhs starts with root, rhs doesn't, so lhs comes first
        return true
    }

    // rhs starts with root, lhs doesn't, so rhs comes first
    if (startsWith(rhs, root)) {
        return false
    }

    // return the normal string comparison
    return lhs < rhs
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Antonio, but i marked @leonardo-savio-dabus answer as the solution as within yours it still returns the strings like "Bonn", "Hamburg" and "München" even that the root string "Licht" isn't contained in those.

Comment: @code-K: no problem - I wonder how I could miss that requirement :) I've updated my code to provide the expected results